# How to use "more" as adjective and adverb

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, comparative-constructions, comparative

Where should I use ***more*** as adjective (comparative) and adverb?

> Sometimes, it seems like Mary does things only to make it ***more*** inconvenient for her husband to have a good time when he’s out with his friends.

In the above sentence, the bold word "***more***" is used as adverb (I think). So in which case should I use ***more*** as adjective (comparative)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When "more" is used before adjective or adverb as "inconvenient" in your example, it is an adverb whose primary function is to modify the following word.

However, when it is used before a noun (or sometimes after a noun), it is used as a determiner or adjective. For example:

> I need more money.
>   More context is required.
>
> I need something more (to eat).

In the above examples, it means:

> greater in amount, number, or size, extra or additional

Comment: Can you rephrase the quote, which I have posted as question, into a comparative? So that I can understand more easily.